# Why doesn't nohup sh -c "..." store variable?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, nohup

**Why doesn't "nohup sh -c" stores variable?**

```
$ nohup sh -c "RU=ru" &
[1] 17042
[1]+  Done                    nohup sh -c "RU=ru"
$ echo ${RU}

$ RU=ru
$ echo ${RU}
ru
```

**How do I make it such that it store the variable value so that I can use in a loop later?**

For now, it's not recording the value when I use `RU=ru` instead my bash loop, i.e.

```
nohup sh -c "RU=ru; for file in *.${RU}-en.${RU}; do some_command ${RU}.txt; done" &
```

It doesn't work within the `sh -c "..."` too, cat nohup.out outputs nothing for the `echo`:

```
$ nohup sh -c "FR=fr; echo ${FR}" &
[1] 17999
[1]+  Done                    nohup sh -c "FR=fr; echo ${FR}"
$ cat nohup.out
```

Comment: `sh -c` starts a new process; there is no way for a variable set in that process to be available to the shell that runs `sh -c`. This has nothing to do with `nohup`.

Comment: does that mean I have to hardcode everywhere in the script when I use that variable? It doesn't work within the `sh -c "..."` too =(

Comment: Are you looking for the `export` command? `export RU=ru` will make `RU` available in any process started by the current shell. (`RU=ru` would make available in the shell itself, but not to any children.)

Comment: `$FR` is in double quotes, so it is expanded before `sh -c` actually runs. It would work with single quotes.

Comment: Wow, the single quote trick works! It's sort of black magic... Any idea why does it expand the $FR that soon?

Comment: Expansion is happening when parameters are evaluated -- surprised? ;-) Perhaps one can add that the shell does not have a notion of sh being a subshell or nohup being somehow special. The current shell just performs parameter substitution on the tokens on the command line. Imagine `cp "$f" "$dir"`. Of course one wants the shell to expand the parameters to a command. Double quotes are essential to preserve strings with spaces as single tokens. Only single quotes explicitly prevent evaluation of variables.

Comment: Because that's what the shell does: it performs parameter expansion in double-quoted strings before it actually runs the command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why doesn't "nohup sh -c" stores variable?

Environment variables only live in a process, and potentially children of a process. When you run `sh -c` you are creating a new child process. Any environment variables in that child process cannot "move up" to the parent process. That's simply how shells and environment variables work.

> It doesn't work within the sh -c "..." too, cat nohup.out outputs
>   nothing for the echo"

The reason for this is that you are using double quotes. When you use double quotes, the shell does variable expansion *before running the command*. If you switch to single quotes, the variable won't be expanded until the shell command runs:

```
nohup sh -c 'FR=fr; echo ${FR}'
```